# sudo apt-get install python3-pip not working

Tags: python, update, pip

[image: Getting 404 Not found. Even after update and upgrade. Any idea?]

Getting 404 Not found when trying to install python-pip3. Error persists even after update and upgrade. Any idea?

Comment: What version of raspbien are you using? Is it buster?

Comment: start by running `sudo apt update` then try again.

Comment: DO NOT post pictures of text post text

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be running Raspbian Wheezy. This is seriously outdated and the best solution is to start fresh with the current Raspbian Buster.

The reason you don't get updates is that the Raspbian Wheezy repo has been moved to a different location and may soon be removed/discontinued completely.

Change `archive.raspbian.org` to `legacy.raspbian.org` in `/etc/apt/sources.list` to access this the repo.

See https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=66&t=237469

Comment: Where do you see that it's Wheezy?

Comment: @Ingo top line in the image. Starts with 'Err' then location and 'wheezy/main python3-pip', etc

Comment: @Ingo Python version 3.2 is also pre-Jessie.

Comment: Thankyou Dirk. I installed recent version and it worked.